# Passing UserID into Datatables

Tags: php, jquery, html, datatable

Working a Project here and I need some help. I have a php page and an html page, trying to pass the username of the php into a DataTable that is in my html file. The code that I have for each is:

PHP is below:

```
public function __construct(Guard $auth)if (Auth::check() ||Auth::attempt()) {
$auth_id = Auth::user()->id;}
```

My HTML portion is the following:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
                                // Makes one continuous line 
        "autoWidth": false,
                                // How many rows to return 
      "pageLength": 25,
                                // Setup the search box with the current username to filter the values on the screen - jsg 2/12/2016
    "search": {
        "search": $('auth')
      }, dom: "Bfrtip",
    ajax: "../php/staff.php",
    columns: [
        {
            data: null,
            defaultContent: '',
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            orderable: false
        },
        { data: "instructor", visible: false },
        { data: "first_name" },
        { data: "last_name" },
        { data: "category" },
        { data: "Metric_text" },
        { data: "response_value" },
        { data: "fkey_course_id", visible: false  },
        { data: "course_code" },
        { data: "course_number" },
        { data: "course_section"}
    ],
```

My Question is how can I get $auth_id into the search portion of the HTML coding. As you can see I've tried this with $('auth') but its giving me an object error. If I trying a name like "search": "Test" then test populates and it works. Basically I want to pass the username into the search box of the DataTable so it ill show only the usernames rows.

Comment: You'll have to pass through the `$auth_id` variable to your Javascript, either with `ajax` or by writing the variable value to the page output in some way.

Comment: `"search": '<?php echo $auth_id; ?>'`

Comment: adding the php simply shows it in the search box when executed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Ajax.

The code looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "scripts/ids-objects.php",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "first_name" },
            { "data": "last_name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

Look at [this](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/ids.html) sample.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: The code uses ajax, see above I added the ajax that I current have into the example.